# Formula with range criteria to search for specific value

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet in google sheets.

I am creating a character sheet for a upcoming pathfinder game and I am currently working on the feats page. I have the page arranged so that Col A is the level in which I will get the feat, Col B is the feat name, Col C is the prerequisites for the feat, and Col D is where I am creating the formula that will tell me if all the requirements have been met.

> Level | Name | Prerequisites | Met?
>
> 1 | Dodge | None
>
> 1 | Mobility | Dodge | Formula
>
> 2 | Spring Attack | Mobility | Formula
>
> 3 | Whirlwind Attack | Spring Attack | Formula

What I am trying to do is create some sort of lookup. I want to limit the range of level (Col A) based on my characters level (lets use Z3 as the cell reference). So if I am level 2, it will only check feats that are level 2 or less. Then I need to make sure the feat name is listed in the reduced Col B.

If there is a better or easier method than a lookup, feel free to let me know.

So assuming that level is set to 1, the formula for Spring Attack would produce a true statement, and the formula for Whirlwind attack would produce a false, because spring attack isnt taken until level 2, and I am only level 1. Once my level changes to 2, then whirlwind should also read true.

Comment: Why should whirlwind read "true" when your level is 2? Its level is 3 in your example.

Comment: Because the requirements to take it have been met, since I simplified things other requirements are not shown, but an example would be I need a base attack bonus of +4 (4 or greater), Spring attack, Mobility, and Dodge. This is only that the prerequisites for the feat have been met, not the feat has been taken.

Comment: Okay. It looks like you will have a separate formula for each feat, which will display True or False. If so, I don't see why you would need anything like lookup. The formula in, say, D4 will refer to the cell A4 for the relevant level, and use it in the computation.

Comment: How am I suppose to do that? I have multiple level 1 feats, and there are/will be levels that I either gain multiple feats or none. So I need to first trim the list down to only the levels I have taken, and search within that range. If I can figure out some way to get that range then I believe I can work the rest of it out, but Im stumped with the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relevant Google Sheets formula is [`filter`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en). For example,

```
=filter(B2:B, A2:A <= 2)
```

returns the list of entries from column B (feat names) where the corresponding entry in column A (level) is at most 2.

One can apply multiple filters, for example

```
=filter(B2:B, A2:A <= 2, C2:C = "string")
```

additionally requires the entry in C to be "string".

When there are no matches, the `filter` returns N/A. This can be used to produce True/False values predicated on finding at least one cell that meets the conditions:

```
=not(isna(filter(B2:B, A2:A <= 2, C2:C = "string")))
```

is True if there was a match and False otherwise.

Comment: I have not used filter before and it seems to do most of what I need. When the feat name isnt found however it throws NA.

Comment: And Iferror has taken care of that issue, thank you so much for your help.